# Android ListView onTouchEvent doesn't always give ACTION_DOWN

Tags: android, listview, touch-event

My problem is that when I try to drag an item in my ListView, I don't always get the ACTION_DOWN event. I got lots of ACTION_MOVE events and only one ACTION_UP event.
It is not always the case. I got ACTION_DOWN 3 times. It confused me.

I looked at similar questions but it's answers seems not fit to mine . Can anyone think of why this is happening?

Thanks

```
//list_client  --  a listview
list_client.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    float f1 = -1, f2 = -1 ;
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
                f1 = event.getRawY();
                    break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                f2 = event.getRawY();
                if(f2 - f1 > 50){
                    if(View.VISIBLE != rl_search_and_add.getVisbility() &&  ){  rl_search_and_add.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                f1 = f2;
                }else if (f2 - f1 < -50){
                    rl_search_and_add.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    f1 = f2;
                }
                break; 
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                f1 = -1; f2 = -1;
                break; 
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello, when a drag is done, you should get one ACTION_DOWN, then multiple ACTION_MOVE and lastly one ACTION_UP. Is it the case ?

Comment: But, i got lots of ACTION_MOVE，and i also got ACTION_UP everytime, but i got ACTION_DOWN only 5 times. Yesterday i got ACITON_UP 2 times.It is not interesting.It is terrible.

Comment: Some guys told me something i do not know consuming the ACTION_DOWN?

Comment: Have you read the doc http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html ? ACTION_DOWN is fired when a finger touches the screen (gesture started), ACTION_UP is fired when the finger is leaving the screen and ACTION_MOVE is fired when the finger is moving (so many times). What's bothering you ?

Comment: Sorry, forgive mine poor English. Maybe i did not describe it clearly.I could not get ACTION_DOWN when I　drag my device for so many times. Maybe I got one in ten times.

Comment: I think the question is I lost the way which the MotionEvent is delivered and consumed .

Comment: ok. Can you add a bit of code (especially when you are defining your list client) ?

Comment: I was just thinking, the onTouch method should probably return true if the event is consumed. Yours is always returning false...

Comment: Thank you.I thought my question was different from others.But it was similar.They have the same way to solve.What causes these questions may come from two methods, public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) from ViewGroup or  public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) from AbsListView. The way to solve is to overwrite onInterceptTouchEvent. There may be something wrong with my thought.

Comment: So as far as I understand, some view is intercepting the event. Have you a complex layout ? To look a bit further, you can try to override onTouchEvent(MotionEvent) in your activity

Comment: Oh, i will have a try. But i really never thought to override onTouchEvent(MotionEvent) in any activity. My layout is just a common one.Maybe it is a little complex...

Answer (score 1):

There could be several reasons for that behavior.

- It is possible that the user missed the list a bit and the `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` been handled by other component, but how ever the user continue dragging and hit your list view area, you received `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` actions.
- Another possibility is that, you had to many events, and they been moved to historical event, and you only received the latest event. You can use all the historical methods of [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) to see them.

Answer (score 0):

you should override onInterceptTouchEvent like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            yDown = event.getRawY();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
}
```

then  using yDown to your program